# Problem with nested minted listing inside a tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

I want to insert some JAVA code in the lower part of a `tcolorbox` (see figure). When I simply use a `tcolorbox`it works but with `\DeclareTotalTColorBox` it didn’t. The following MEW gives further details.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[all]{tcolorbox}

% Command that should accept a tcblisting as a second mandatory. It leads to a compilation error when used.
\DeclareTotalTColorBox{\javaapp}{ O{red} m m}{enhanced,colframe=#1!75!black,colback=#1!5!white,title=JAVA application}
 {
  #2
  \tcblower
  #3
 }

% Command that should accept a JAVA code as a second mandatory. It leads to a compilation error when used.
\DeclareTotalTColorBox{\javaappwithminted}{ O{red} m m }{enhanced,colframe=#1!75!black,colback=#1!5!white,title=JAVA application}
 {
  #2
  \tcblower
  \begin{tcblisting}{listing engine=minted,minted style=trac,minted language=java,
   colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,listing only,enhanced,nobeforeafter,skin=enhancedmiddle jigsaw,interior hidden,leftrule=0mm,rightrule=0mm,boxsep=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm}
   #3
  \end{tcblisting}
 }

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,colframe=red!75!black,colback=red!5!white,title=JAVA application]
  Write a 'Hello Word' java class
 \tcblower
  \begin{tcblisting}{listing engine=minted,minted style=trac,minted language=java,
     colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,listing only,enhanced,nobeforeafter,skin=enhancedmiddle jigsaw,interior hidden,leftrule=0mm,rightrule=0mm,boxsep=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm}
public class HelloWorld {
    // A ’Hello World’ in Java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
\end{tcblisting}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is the `verbatim` content of the 2nd mandatory argument. This does not work this way, but also using `m` instead of `+m`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that verbatim content can't be nested directly into other content.

The end of `tcblisting` isn't correctly recognized then and an error is generated -- `TeX` must see the 'string' `\endtcblisting` then, which can be achieved by a rescan of the content with `\scantokens`.

In order to provide nice output, use the `+v` argument specifier (+ for multiline with `\par` and `v` for verbatim), not `m` or `+m`.

```
\DeclareTotalTColorBox{\javaappwithminted}{ O{red}+m+v }{enhanced,colframe=#1!75!black,colback=#1!5!white,title=JAVA application}
 {
  #2
  \tcblower
  \scantokens{%
  \begin{tcblisting}{listing engine=minted,minted style=trac,minted language=java,
      colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,listing only,enhanced,nobeforeafter,skin=enhancedmiddle jigsaw,interior hidden,leftrule=0mm,rightrule=0mm,boxsep=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm}
    #3
    \end{tcblisting}
  }
}
```

Here's the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[all]{tcolorbox}

% Command that should accept a tcblisting as a second mandatory. It leads to a compilation error when used.
\DeclareTotalTColorBox{\javaapp}{ O{red} m m}{enhanced,colframe=#1!75!black,colback=#1!5!white,title=JAVA application}
 {
  #2
  \tcblower
  #3
 }

% Command that should accept a JAVA code as a second mandatory. It leads to a compilation error when used.
\DeclareTotalTColorBox{\javaappwithminted}{ O{red}+m+v }{enhanced,colframe=#1!75!black,colback=#1!5!white,title=JAVA application}
 {
  #2
  \tcblower
  \scantokens{%
  \begin{tcblisting}{listing engine=minted,minted style=trac,minted language=java,
      colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,listing only,enhanced,nobeforeafter,skin=enhancedmiddle jigsaw,interior hidden,leftrule=0mm,rightrule=0mm,boxsep=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm}
    #3
    \end{tcblisting}
  }
}





\begin{document}

\javaappwithminted{%
  Foo
}{%
  public class HelloWorld {

    // A ’Hello World’ in Java

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
  }
 }


\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,colframe=red!75!black,colback=red!5!white,title=JAVA application]
  Write a 'Hello Word' java class
  \tcblower
  \begin{tcblisting}{listing engine=minted,minted style=trac,minted language=java,
      colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,listing only,enhanced,nobeforeafter,skin=enhancedmiddle jigsaw,interior hidden,leftrule=0mm,rightrule=0mm,boxsep=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm}
    public class HelloWorld {
      // A ’Hello World’ in Java
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
      }
}
\end{tcblisting}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you are a gift. It works like a charm.

Comment: @ALOUI: Happy TeXing then! ;-)