# Nesting tcolorboxes with listing

Tags: tcolorbox, minted, nesting

I'm trying to build a macro to ouput the content in a `tcolorbox`.
Ultimately, any kind of content can be put in that box (image, tcolorbox, code, ...).

However, when using the macro (instead of the direct box construction), newlines do not appear anymore, **although it's the same tcolorbox options**.

I've read from [another answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/307135/28926) that there are problems with the closing macro, that's why I've added the `\scantokens` in the macro.

Here is the MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[all]{tcolorbox}

\usemintedstyle{default}% colorful, pastie
\setminted{
    tabsize=2,
    fontsize=\footnotesize,
    fontfamily=tt,
    autogobble=true,
    breaklines=true,
}

\tcbset{snippetstyle/.style={
        listing only,
        listing engine=minted,
        enhanced jigsaw,
        breakable,
        colback=black!20,
        colframe=blue,
        sharp corners,
        size=small,
        autoparskip,
        parbox=false,
    }
}

\DeclareTCBListing{codeBloc}{m}{%
    snippetstyle,
    minted language=#1,
    minted options={numbersep=10pt,numbers=left},
}%



\DeclareTotalTColorBox{\sameBoxInMacro}{ +m }{enhanced jigsaw,title=JAVA application}
{
    \scantokens{%
        #1
    }
}



\begin{document}

\section{Macro used to build the tcolorbox}
Wrong behavior : no newlines

\sameBoxInMacro{%
    This is a sample code

    \begin{codeBloc}{Python}
        import socket
        def client(string):
        HOST, PORT = 'localhost', 2000
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
        sock.send(string)
        reply = sock.recv(16384)  # limit reply to 16K
        sock.close()
        return reply
        assert client('2+2') == '4'
    \end{codeBloc}
}%


\section{tcolorbox directly build without macro}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced jigsaw,title=JAVA application]
    This is a sample code
    
    \begin{codeBloc}{Python}
        import socket
        def client(string):
        HOST, PORT = 'localhost', 2000
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
        sock.send(string)
        reply = sock.recv(16384)  # limit reply to 16K
        sock.close()
        return reply
        assert client('2+2') == '4'
    \end{codeBloc}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

And its output :

[image: MWE output]

Altough the 2 boxes have the same definition, the 1st is called via a macro `\sameBoxInMacro` while the latter is build directly via a `\begin{tcolorbox}`.

**How can I make the macro I've buit respect the newlines in the content ?**

Comment: After a one-step expansion of `\sameBoxInMacro`, the (single) newlines in its argument are converted to spaces, and the conversion cannot be reverted by `\scantokens`.  To keep the newlines, normal tricks/popular implementations are to write to external file then read in it, unfortunately using an environment to delimit the verbatim content. An environment is used because I guess matching `\end{<envname>}` is much easier than a paired brace.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you have any links of such implementations ?

Comment: [`fancyvrb`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb) provides one of such implementations, which is used by `minted` and `tcolorbox` with `listing engine=minted`.

Comment: And via `tcolorbox`, isn't there a mean to save that in an external file and re-use it directly ?